# Adding Android jars to Eclipse Build Path

Tags: android, eclipse, classpath

I am using Linux Fedora 16 OS.  Eclipse Indigo.

Android SDK as well as its associated Eclipse plugin have been installed successfully.

However, when I imported a sample project I downloaded, the build errors indicated that the compiler could not find the Android classes in the classpath, i.e. the Android jars did not automatically get added to the Eclipse classpath when installing the plugin.

I tried adding all the jars that are in the /android/tools/lib directory (like a lot of them)  but that didn't do it.

So I am wondering if this jar(s) need to be downloaded separately, i.e. are not part of the SDK package (which seems doubtful).

Error example:

android.app.Activity cannot be resolved to a type

Answer (score 1):

in Eclipse when you have import as project of android ,check root directory of you project and check it have following thing in it ,like below

```
 .project
 AndroidManifest.xml
```

if your imported project of android doesn't have .project then you should import project like below step :

in Eclipse go to:

File-->New-->Android Project -->now you have some option to check if you want to add Project that have already source code then select Project from exiting Source and find your Project root directory.

Now one more thing when you have imported project Right Click on Project root Directory and Click on properties go to Android -->then if there is no selected build target then select one of Android Target as your required.

Comment: Thanks.  i do have AndroidManifest.xml and it specifies the min SDK level requirement of 8, and target of 11.  however, my AVD is set to 15 (version 4.0.3.).  could that be what the problem is?  doesn't seem like it should

Comment: No AVD Version 4.0.3 will not create any problem,still you can not able to see any Android Lib in your project.Let me known.and you must check your project has .project file in it.

Comment: I do have a .project file, here are its contents:

Comment: i can't post the XML contents of the .project file.  this web site is incredibly Nazi about rules and restrictions...  it's almost like a programming language in itself ... SMH

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I faced this issue too. Sometimes, while importing android source code eclipse does not add android framework jars to build path. In that case open the .classpath file (It will be in the root folder of your project) and add the line

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
```

after the source classpath entries. Refresh, clean and build the project. You will find android framework added to your project's build path